# How can I set separate phase 1 and phase 2 IPs using AWS Managed IPSec offerring?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, ipsec, site-to-site-vpn

I'm trying to setup an AWS Site-to-Site VPN connection that is IPSec based. It seems to be their managed offering. A particular connection I am trying to setup specifies distinct Phase 1 and Phase 2 IP addresses. I'm wondering how I can configure in AWS. In the UI and documentation (and Terraform AWS provider documentation) this doesn't seem to be possible, but knowing AWS this could just be a poorly documented or difficult to figure out configuration.

Thanks!